# How to register a DLL in a Web Api installation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

In a Web Api project, created in Visual Studio 2012, I need to register a DLL because it is a COM component. I need to use the REGSV32 app. When I create the Web Deploy package, under Visual Studio, where I can specify the additional files and command line options?

Comment: As long as your DLLs are included in the package, in the bin folder, your application should be ready to use the DLLs -- is there something else you're needing?

Comment: @Alpha: regsvr32ed dll is apparently a COM dll. It is not enough to just put in in the \bin folder.

Comment: I need to register them because they are COM

Comment: @DabielKabuto: for few years COMs don't have to be registered. There exists a technique called "registration free com activation" which consists in writing a manifest file. This supposedly should be possible in asp.net, however I havent tried it by myself http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxs/help/iis6aspnet2.htm